# Why does sed s/// (empty pattern and replacement) remove a particular string?

Tags: sed

I have two files: junk.txt and lines.txt

```
$>cat junk.txt
This is a junk text
$>cat lines.txt
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

When I fire the following `sed` script

```
 sed -i -e  "/Line3/r junk.txt" -e "s///" lines.txt
```

I get this output:

```
Line1
Line2

This is a junk text
Line4
```

As you can see, `Line3` is no more there. Ok, the `/Line3/r junk.txt` part finds the text in the lines.txt matching Line3 and appends the contents of the junk.txt. But why does the `s///` command remove exactly the matched line?

To be honest, that's the behavior I need but I want to know why it behaves like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the editing command `s` is invoked with an empty regular expression, it reuses the expression most recently used.  In this case, it reuses `Line3` from the matching of it earlier. This applies to `//` (empty regular expressions) in both the `s` command and in address ranges.

Your command could also be written, without this feature, as

```
sed -i -e '/Line3/r junk.txt' -e 's/Line3//' lines.txt
```

The `Line3` text is removed because it is replaced by nothing.

You would sometimes see this in constructs like

```
/expression/ {
    s//replacement/
    # other code here
}
```

The [POSIX specification for `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html) formulates this as

> If an RE is empty (that is, no pattern is specified) sed shall behave as if the last RE used in the last command applied (either as an address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.

Comment: This was also my interpretation, i.e. similar to vim, but I couldn't find any official mention of this in [the sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Do you know if it's documented anywhere?

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. So "s/text-to-replace/replace-with". If we omit the replace-with, it's going to replace it with nothing and if we go further and omit the text-to-replace it uses the recent expression to match, which in this case is Line3. That makes sense.

Comment: @Sparhawk `vi`, `sed`, and `ed` are all the same editor, and `vim` is `vi`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Check [section 4.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses).